# HERE Tour planning more then seven shifts

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I'm just exploring the potential of here API and i noticed that shifts array can hold a maximum of seven element.

But if i have the same vehicle that works for one month what i have to do?
Create one vehicle type for every week? Or create just one shift that start at the first day of the month, end on the last and then set the appropriate breaks?

I already search in documentation but is not clear how to set more then seven shift.

This is the response that i get

> 400 Bad Request: "{"title":"OpenApi validation
> error","status":400,"code":"E613000","cause":"[Path
> '/fleet/types/0/shifts'] Array is too long: must have at most 7
> elements but instance has 365 elements","action":"Problem definition
> is not consistent with the specification. Please correct problem and
> send it
> again.","correlationId":"e2531ee0-1b57-4848-86a9-1403d358bef6"}"

Comment: Could you please point me to the documentation/content where it states that shifts can hold only max of 7 elements?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport
in this page https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/3.4/api-reference-swagger.html

In Submit a Vehicle Routing Problem to solve it synchronously
Fleet -> Types -> Shifts

Also,i inserted the error that i receive if i made a request

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that maximum shifts to be defined is 7. If a user really needs to plan more shifts, it is possible to replicate the vehicle types with different dates. Another option is to plan the tour and use the tour on daily basis - perhaps there is the same daily delivery schedule.